# How to get color name in simple product?

Tags: magento-1.9

I used

```
echo $_product->getColor()
```

but i will print code = 24 , instead of color name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this :

```
$_product->getAttributeText('color');
```

Answer (score 5):

`$_product->getColor()` will return optionId not text so for Text use below code

If it is dropdown then right syntax for printing value is

```
$_product->getAttributeText('Attribute_code');
```

And In your case its `$_product->getAttributeText('color');`